# Need to use same input for multiple outputs in Shiny

Tags: r, render, shiny

I'm trying to code an app with tabs in Shiny that makes reference to the same input from a text box.

Input:

`column(2, textInput(inputId = "sh1", label = "Stakeholder #1's name"))`

Output:

```
tabPanel("#1 vs #2",
                          fluidRow(
                              column(3),
                              column(2, textOutput(outputId = "sh1o")),
                              column(2, "vs"),
                              column(2, textOutput(outputId = "sh2o"))
                          ),

tabPanel("#1 vs #3",
                          fluidRow(
                              column(3),
                              column(2, textOutput(outputId = "sh1o")),
                              column(2, "vs"),
                              column(2, textOutput(outputId = "sh3o"))
                          ),
```

Rendering:

`output$sh1o <- renderText(input$sh1)`

As I have learn, Shiny wont allow an input to be used more than once.

Is there any way to make this work?

Can the same input get assigned to a temp variable and then to the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shiny allows input to be used as many times as you want, but you can't use the same `outputId` for output elements. You could rename your `textOutput` `outputId`s by adding the name of the tab first to make them unique.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Test"),
        sidebarPanel(textInput(inputId = "sh1", label = "Stakeholder #1's name")),
                mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("#1 vs #2",
                         fluidRow(
                                 column(3),
                                 column(2, textOutput(outputId = "tab1_sh1o")),
                                 column(2, "vs"),
                                 column(2, textOutput(outputId = "tab1_sh2o"))
                         )),

                         tabPanel("#1 vs #3",
                                  fluidRow(
                                          column(3),
                                          column(2, textOutput(outputId = "tab2_sh1o")),
                                          column(2, "vs"),
                                          column(2, textOutput(outputId = "tab2_sh3o"))
                                  )
        )
))))

server <- function(input,output,session){
        output$tab1_sh1o <- renderText(input$sh1)
        output$tab1_sh2o <- renderText(input$sh1)
        output$tab2_sh1o <- renderText(input$sh1)
        output$tab2_sh3o <- renderText(input$sh1)
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much!!

I was trying something myself following the same kind of thought process using variables:

`ui <- fluidPage(
  
  textInput(inputId = "p1", label = "P1"),
  textOutput(outputId = "po1"),
  textOutput(outputId = "po2")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x <- renderText(input$p1)
  output$po1 <- x
  output$po2 <- x
  
}`

However, yours seems more elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help, if the answer was helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help.